# Scroll UITableView to certain indexPath depending on selection

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView with a custom cell. The custom cell as three buttons covering the entire span of the cell. I am trying to scroll the tableview automatically depending on which label the user selects.

I tried using NotificationCenter but it crashes when trying to scroll. Is there a more elegant solution?

Edit: My end goal is to have the user click on optionOne and have it scroll to the cell immediately below. The trick is doing this without cellForRowAt because I'm handling it in the cell due to the multiple buttons.

**Custom Cell:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var optionOneLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var optionTwoLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var optionThreeLabel: UILabel!

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    let optionOne = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CustomCell.optionOnePressed(_:)))
    optionOneLabel.addGestureRecognizer(optionOne)

    let optionTwo = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CustomCell.optionTwoPressed(_:)))
    optionTwoLabel.addGestureRecognizer(optionTwo)

    let optionThree = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CustomCell.optionThreePressed(_:)))
    optionThreeLabel.addGestureRecognizer(optionThree) 
}

@objc func optionOnePressed(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "scrollTableOptionOne"), object: nil)
}

@objc func optionTwoPressed(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "scrollTableOptionTwo"), object: nil)
}

@objc func optionThreePressed(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "scrollTableOptionthree"), object: nil)
}
```

**TableViewController**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(optionOne), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "scrollTableOptionOne"), object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(optionTwo), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "scrollTableOptionTwo"), object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(optionThree), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "scrollTableOptionThree"), object: nil)

}

@objc func optionOne() {
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(item: posts.count, section: 0)
    tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.init(rawValue: indexPath.row + 2)!, animated: true)
}

@objc func optionTwo() {
    print("Don't scroll this one for now")
}

@objc func optionThree() {
    print("Don't scroll this one for now")
}
```

Let me know if you need more information. Thanks.

Comment: Are you having single section or multiple?

Comment: What does the crash report say? Also, don't add notifications in `prepareForReuse` because you would end up adding multiple gestures of the same type since you are not removing the gestures added the first time.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use notifications, you could set up a callback on the cell with the buttons so that when one of them is tapped, the callback is run with the information about which button was tapped so that the view controller can do what it needs to with it:

As an example of what you want to do I've created a sample project which you can download and look at (Xcode 9.4.1, Swift 4.1) It's a bit messy, but it does what you need: https://bitbucket.org/abizern/so51758928/src/master/

The specifics are, firstly, set up the cell with the buttons to handle the callback:

```
class SelectionCell: UITableViewCell {
    enum Button {
        case first
        case second
        case third
    }

    var callback: ((Button) -> Void)?

    @IBAction func firstButtonSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {
        callback?(.first)
    }

    @IBAction func secondButtonSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {
        callback?(.second)
    }

    @IBAction func thirdButtonSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {
        callback?(.third)
    }
}
```

Using an enum for the buttons makes the code cleaner than just raw numbers to identify a button. Each button calls the callback identifying itself.

In the table view controller, when you set up the cells in the delegate, you pass this callback to the cell:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let value = values[indexPath.row]
    switch value {
    case .header:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Selection", for: indexPath) as! SelectionCell
        cell.callback = handler
        return cell
    case .value:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Display", for: indexPath) as! DisplayCell
        cell.configure(with: value)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Note, I've passed `handler` not `handler()` so that it passed the closure, not the result of running the closure, to the cell. It's the cell that runs the closure.

The callback looks like this (for my example, your needs will be different)
I'm using the button identifier that is passed in to the closure to identify the IndexPath that I'm interested in and scrolling it to the top

```
private func handler(button: SelectionCell.Button) -> Void {
    print("selected \(button)")
    let index: Int?
    switch button {
    case .first:
        index = values.index(where: { (value) -> Bool in
            if case .value("First") = value {
            return true
            }
            return false
        })

    case .second:
        index = values.index(where: { (value) -> Bool in
            if case .value("Second") = value {
                return true
            }
            return false
        })
    case .third:
        index = values.index(where: { (value) -> Bool in
            if case .value("Third") = value {
                return true
            }
            return false
        })
    }
    guard let row = index else { return }
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)

    tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
}
```

As I've already said, you can look at the example project to see how this all works, but these are the important steps.

Answer (score 1):

Use the cell that sends the notification as the sender object instead of nil. In your cell do:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(
    name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "scrollTableOptionOne"), 
    object: self)
```

Change your notification handler so that it can access to the notification. Retrieve the cell from the notification and find out the indexPath.

```
@objc func optionOne(ntf: Notification) {
    let cell = ntf.object as! UITableViewCell
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, 
          at: .bottom, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the reason for crashing.

> For performance reasons, you should only reset attributes of the cell
>   that are not related to content, for example, alpha, editing, and
>   selection state. The table view's delegate in
>   tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) should always reset all content when
>   reusing a cell

[Refer this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse)

You can make use of **Closures** or **Delegate** instead of going with notification

Comment: Hmm okay. I could see if I set the delegate of the cell to the tableview I could have the button cause an action...but that still doesn't resolve the issue of scrolling the tableview one row down upon button click. Or does it?:)

Comment: @CaseyWest Scrolling to that index wont be a issue.

Comment: would you be able to give me a hint on that part? Having issues still.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change code like this

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: posts.count - 1, section: 0)
tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
```

This will scroll your row to top in table view.

Comment: Hmm...okay thanks for the info. My end goal is to actually scroll to the cell below the current one, assuming there is one there. I'll update the question to reflect that. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

ScrollToRow method having some problem. `UITableViewScrollPosition` holds the values - **none**, **top**, **middle**, **bottom** enum values.

Change the line:

```
 tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.init(rawValue: indexPath.row + 2)!, animated: true)
```

To:

```
tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
```

In order to track indexpath, set row value to cell's tag, in `cellForRow:`

```
cell.tag = indexPath.row
```

And post notification as:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "scrollTableOptionOne"), object: self.tag)

@objc func optionOne(_ notification: Notification) {
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(item: notification.object+1, section: 0)
    tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.init(rawValue: indexPath.row + 2)!, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Better approach will be using `closures`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var optionOneLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var optionTwoLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var optionThreeLabel: UILabel!

var callBackOnLabel : (()->())? /// Add this in cell.

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code

    let optionOne = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CustomCell.optionOnePressed(_:)))
    optionOneLabel.addGestureRecognizer(optionOne)

 }

@objc func optionOnePressed(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.callBackOnLabel?()
}
```

Then in your `cellForRowAt`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 

    cell.callBackOnLabel = {
        let selectedIndex = IndexPath(row: posts.count, section: 0)

        tableView.scrollToRow(at: selectedIndex, at: .middle, animated: true)
    }
}
```

In the same way you can add for other two `labels` or you can make it generic to accept the response in single call back and perform the animation.