# How to change Color of cell in UiCollectionView if just two can be selected

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, button, uicollectionviewcell

I am used button inside UICollectionView cell, and I want to button can change color just two indexes and other can't change color if click other  buttons `uicolor.clear`

[image]

and I want to like this, so how to use `sender.backgroundColor`

[image]

```
func collectionView(_: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellB", for: indexPath) as! BandingCollectionViewCell

            cell.bBandingCell.addTarget(self, action: #selector(masterAction3(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        return cell
    }
```

{

```
@objc func masterAction3(_ sender: UIButton) {
        var indexPath = collectionView.indexPath(for: ((sender.superview?.superview) as! BandingCollectionViewCell))
        if sender.isSelected {
            sender.isSelected = false
            switch indexPath?.row {
            case 0:
                print("0")
                sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            case 1:
                print("1")
                sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

            default:
                print("default")
                sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
            }


        } else {
            sender.isSelected = true
            switch indexPath?.row {
            case 0:
                print("0")
                sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
            case 1:
                print("1")
                sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

            default:
                print("default")
                sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51758928/scroll-uitableview-to-certain-indexpath-depending-on-selection/51760100#51760100 . Implemented in tableview. You can try this in collectionview cell too. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

1. Use custom UICollectionViewCell subclass (without button because collection view cell handles selection itself)
2. in this cell class override `isSelected` property like this:

   ```
   override var isSelected: Bool {
       didSet {
           // set color according to state
           self.backgroundColor = self.isSelected ? .blue : .clear 
       }
   }
   ```
3. In class which controls your `collectionView` perform `collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true`
4. In your `UICollectionViewDelegate` implement method (which will prevent selection of more than two cells at a time):

   ```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
       return (collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.count ?? 0) < 2
   }
   ```

This way you don't need a button inside the cell.

Answer (score 2):

When you select a cell, `isSelected` will be set. And you can customise your cell like this.

```
class YourCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {


  override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = isSelected ?.blue : .clear
    }  
  }
}
```

***NB***: No need to add actions manually. Remove your selector method